# Is it possible to call a subclass virtual function from within superclass implementation?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    Parent() {}
    virtual void foo() { cout << "My favorite song is:"; bar(); }
    virtual void bar() {}
};

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    Child() : Parent() {}
    virtual void bar() { cout << "Singing in the Rain"; }
    void baz() { Parent::foo(); }
};

int main()
{
      Child().baz(); // Outputs "My favorite song is: Singing in the Rain"
      return 0;
}
```

The answer is YES. The above code works as expected.

Comment: What happened when you tried it out?

Comment: BTW this is a technique used to implement the template method pattern in C++.

Comment: *Facepalm* - I thought I was doing this exact thing in my code and it appeared to not be working so I thought there was something wrong. Turns out the only thing wrong is my code! This is definitely possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to call a subclass virtual function from within superclass implementation?

It is certainly possible. But you need to actually establish that inheritance relationship. For instance:

```
class Child : public Parent
//          ^^^^^^^^
//          For instance...
{
public: // Make at least baz() accessible from the outside
    // ...
}; // <== And don't forget the semicolon here
```

And you also need to give member functions in the base class proper accessibility if they have to be invoked by `Child`:

```
class Parent
{
public: // <== For instance, you could make the member functions public
    virtual void foo() { cout << "My favorite song is:"; bar(); }
    virtual void bar() {}
}; // <== Do not forget this
```

For a complete example, see this [**live demo**](http://ideone.com/McMH7Z).

Comment: Why the `public` inheritance? I may be overlooking something, but the only thing I see that relies on it is `Child::baz`, and that can "see" the base class regardless of accessibility. I wouldn't have asked if you just used `public` as a sensible default, but you specifically mark the `public` keyword there with `^^^^^^^^`.

Comment: @hvd: That was just an example. I simply wanted to mention that an inheritance relationship needs to be there, and wanted to show a way to make the code compile.

Comment: The above code was meant to be pseudo-code, although I did forget to show that the Child really was a child of Parent. Turns out I came to this question with a bunch of wrong assumptions, and I'm kind of embarrassed about it now...

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to call a subclass virtual function from within superclass implementation?

Yes, but beware when doing this from within the constructors and destructor, since the type of the object evolves as different constructors/destructors complete. In particular during the execution of the `Parent` constructor/destructor, the type of the object is `Parent` regardless of the type of the whole object being constructed.

There are a couple of smells in the code (other than the obvious syntactic errors that the compiler will catch and the lack of inheritance). For example, `foo` is a virtual function in the base, but in the implementation of `Child::baz` you are explicitly calling that override (i.e. disabling dynamic dispatch), which might be intentional or not (you could just call `foo()`).